How to finish or redirect a screen flow from the first screen?
My requirement is : I Have a screen flow with only 1 screen that is launched from a button on the Incident List view to bulk change owner. When the user clicks the button it launches the First Screen asking him to choose if he wants to change owner to group or user. I ´ve made a custom button lwc with the buttons Next and Cancel and what i need is that when the users clicks on cancel they need to be redirected to the list view. The next button works perfect , but the cancel button does not work.
I´ve tried navigation mixin to the list view and also tried to finish the flow via the button because we have a automatically redirect via retUrl when the flow finishes. Here´s the code:
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_text-destructive slds-m-right_xx-small"
        onclick={handleNavi}>Cancel</button>

    

    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleGoNext}>Next</button>
</div>

import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import { FlowNavigationNextEvent, FlowNavigationFinishEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
export default class NocOwnerButtons extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@api
availableActions = [];




handleNavi() {
    console.log('Cancel button clicked');
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: "standard__objectPage",
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: "Incident",
            actionName: "list",
        },
        state: {
            // 'filterName' is a property on the page 'state'
            // and identifies the target list view.
            // It may also be an 18 character list view id.
            filterName: "00B8Z00000H4iFLUAZ", // or by 18 char '00BT0000002TONQMA4'
        },
    });

    /*  if (this.availableActions.find((action) => action === 'FINISH')) {
         // navigate to the next screen
         const navigateFinishEvent = new FlowNavigationFinishEvent();
         this.dispatchEvent(navigateFinishEvent);
     } */




}

handleGoNext() {
    
    if (this.availableActions.find((action) => action === 'NEXT')) {
        const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
        this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
    }
}

}
